# Selection.Range not inserting my textbox at the cursor position

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am writing a macro to insert a textbox containing a pre-formatted table into a Microsoft Word document, and I want it to insert the table at the current cursor location. With the current code I have, the textbox seems to be inserted at the beginning or end of the current page, instead of the cursor location.

Here is my code:

```
Sub InsertTable()
    Dim shpTbox As Shape
    Dim rngTbox As Range
    Dim tblBox As Table
    Set shpTbox = ActiveDocument.Shapes.addtextbox( _
        Orientation:=msoTextOrientationHorizontal, _
        Left:=72, Top:=50, Width:=468, Height:=220, Anchor:=Selection.Range)
    shpTbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Tables.Add Range:=shpTbox.TextFrame.TextRange, NumRows:=8, NumColumns:=4, _
        DefaultTableBehavior:=wdWord9TableBehavior, AutoFitBehavior:=wdAutoFitFixed
    shpTbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Tables.Item(1).Select
    shpTbox.TextFrame.TextRange.Tables(1).Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Custom Table")
    Selection.InsertCaption Label:="Figure", _
        Title:=". Insert Caption Here", _
        Position:=wdCaptionPositionBelow
    shpTbox.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    shpTbox.WrapFormat.Type = wdWrapSquare
    shpTbox.WrapFormat.Side = wdWrapBoth
    shpTbox.TextFrame.TextRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = wdAlignParagraphCenter
End Sub
```

Is there a way to do what I want to do? Can someone explain why this doesn't do what I want it to do?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Word positions to the page by default. You need to tell it otherwise, and re-set the `Left` and `Top` properties afterwards. After the TextBox has been inserted specify the relative horizontal and vertical positions. For example:

```
shpTbox.RelativeHorizontalPosition = wdRelativeHorizontalPositionColumn
shpTbox.RelativeVerticalPosition = wdRelativeVerticalPositionLine
shpTbox.Left = 72
shpTbox.Top = 50
```

You may want to test some of the `WdRelativeHorizontalPosition` and `WdRelativeVerticalPostition` enumeration values to see what works best for your situation.